# Proof of open mapping theorem for Fréchet spaces, non-archimedian Version

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

[image]

I have a question concerning the the following proof. I did hightlight the part i can not really get my around, it just beats me why the intersection $y - T(U) \cap \overline{T(U_2)}$ need not be empty. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: which book is that from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y\in \overline{T_1(U)}$, $0\in y-\overline{T_1(U)}=\overline{y-T_1(U)}$.  Since $\overline{T_2(U)}$ is a neighborhood of $0$, this means it must intersect $y-T_1(U)$.